# Compile errors C2059, C2061, C2146, and sporadic IntelliSense error

Tags: c, visual-c++

I'm having some trouble getting my program to compile and I think the majority of the problem now is that I've been looking at it for too long...

**Overview of this *one* part of the program:**  you have a complex number in rectangular form (represented by the structure "Complex") that you want to convert to a complex number in polar form (represented by the structure "pComplex")

Upon trying to build, I'm getting these errors, each three times:

```
"error C2059: syntax error: ')'"  
"error C2059: syntax error: ';'"  
"error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'c1'"  
"error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'c1'"
```

Also, I receive `IntelliSense: identifier "Complex" is undefined` but only until click on the line in question, then it goes away.

All errors point to the same line of the same header file (`pcomplex.h`):

```
pComplex NF_convert_c2_pcdouble(Complex c1);
```

relevant parts of `pcomplex.h`:

```
#ifndef PCOMPLEX_H
#define PCOMPLEX_H
#include "complex.h"
#include <math.h>
//
// ... 
//
typedef struct nf_complex_polar{
    double r;
    double angle;
} pComplex;
//
// ... 
//
pComplex NF_convert_c2_pcdouble(Complex c1);
//
// ... 
//
#endif
```

relevant parts of `complex.h`:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H
#include "pcomplex.h"
#include <math.h>
//
// ... 
//
typedef struct nf_complex{
    double real;
    double imag;
} Complex;
//
// ... 
//
Complex NF_convert_pc2_cdouble(pComplex pc1);
//
// ... 
//
#endif
```

Something else I've noticed, when I hover over the function name in `pcomplex.c`,

```
pComplex NF_convert_c2_pcdouble(Complex c1)
{
    //This function converts a rectangular form complex number c1
    //    and returns it as a polar form complex number pc1
    pComplex pc1;
    double x, y, r, a;
    x = c1.real;
    y = c1.imag;
    r = sqrt( x*x + y*y );
    a = atan2(y,x);
    pc1.r = r;
    pc1.angle = a;
    return pc1;
}
```

I get a little popup box containing this, and I don't know what the second line means:

```
pComplex NF_convert_c2_pcdouble(Complex c1)

pComplex NF_convert_c2_pcdouble(<error-type> c1)
```

Is this enough information and code to merit asking for help in figuring this out? The two header files are about 100 lines each, and the corresponding source files are about 1000 lines...so I tried to keep it relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you coding in C or in C++ ? If coding in C++, defining your **class**-es should be better style.

Having both `pcomplex.h` and `complex.h` include each other is a poor design. The inclusion graph should be a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

I suggest merging the two headers into one single header having both `CartesianComplex` and `PolarComplex` types.

(I guess your teacher don't want you to use the standard headers defining complex numbers)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm coding in C. I merged the two headers and no longer receive the errors.

Answer (score 2):

You define two types, `Complex` and `pComplex`, and you declare two functions, each of which depends on both type definitions.

However you organize your `#include` directives, the compiler needs to see *both* type definitions before it can process the function declarations.

But you have one header that defines one of the types and then declares one of the functions, and another header that defines the other type followed by the other function.  There is no order in which you can compile the headers that will make the type definitions visible where they need to be.

(Note that the `typedef`s are implemented rather oddly in C's grammar, with the result that a reference to `typedef` that hasn't yet been defined generally shows up as a syntax error rather than as a more straightforward "undeclared identifier" error.)

One solution would be to split the type definitions and the function definitions into four separate header files, with `#include` directives to express the dependencies.

A simpler solution is to merge your two header files into one, with the `typedef`s followed by the function declarations.

As Basile says, having two headers include each other is rarely if ever a good idea.  The include guards prevent infinite recursion, but they also prevent some declarations from being visible to code that depends on them.

Comment: +1. I think it leaves two reasonable options. One is to merge the header files. The other is to choose which is the more low level (e.g. rectangular) and which is higher. The higher header can include the lower, and define functions that reference its types, but not vice versa. So both conversion functions would be in the polar header.